# how to find o/p all the student who are enroll in 2 or more courses in sql server using group by?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, having

i have a table name as `testtabl1` now 
 **i want to find all the student who are enroll in 2 or more courses**, 
in this `sid` is the student id and `cid` is the course id

**table structure**

```
create table testtabl1(Sid int,cid int,years varchar(20))
insert into testtabl1(Sid,cid,years)
select 1,1,'2016'
union all
select 2,2,'2017'
union all
select 1,2,'2017'
```

new to sql server and stackoverflow need help !!

tried

```
select sid,COUNT(*),cid from testtabl1 group by sid,cid having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself?

Comment: This is a very commonly posted homework assignment. From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: written tried @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: You have "having" in the tags for the question. Have you tried using it in the query?

Comment: sorry  i forget to use it done now but still not getting desired o/p

Comment: What result are you getting? And what result are you expecting? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sid as StudentId,
       COUNT(cid) as SelectedCoursesCount
FROM testtabl1
GROUP BY sid
HAVING COUNT(cid) > 1;
```